# Certbot / letsencrypt Error with [non-www] domain after generating [www] certificate

Tags: apache, ssl-certificate, ubuntu-18.04, lets-encrypt, certbot

I setup two sites (links below) using certbot and entered the "www." portion of the domain when generating the HTTPS certificate resulting in non-www URL's for both sites causing an error.

There are many similar questions on StackOverflow but none have fixed my issue so far.

**Related Links**

- https://certbot.eff.org/lets-encrypt/ubuntubionic-apache
- https://letsencrypt.org/

**Working Domains**

- https://www.fastsitephp.com/en/
- https://www.dataformsjs.com/#/en/

**Invalid Domains (because of the missing 'www.')**

- https://fastsitephp.com/en/
- https://dataformsjs.com/#/en/

**Attempted Fix Commands**

- sudo certbot certonly --standalone -d fastsitephp.com -d www.fastsitephp.com
- sudo certbot delete --cert-name www.fastsitephp.com

*Chrome will re-direct to the 'www' site using the above links however the error is clear from Firefox and Mobile Safari*

**Server**

- Ubuntu 18.04 LTS with Apache

HELP! What can I do to fix this without having to setup a new server and changing the URL. Ideally the severs would support both www and non-www; however if it can't be fixed an Apache url re-write would also be acceptable.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I ended up solving it myself. The primary issue is that Certbot still leaves the HTTP->HTTPS redirect it created and some other Apache config settings even after running delete (this assumes you selected redirect from HTTP to HTTPS on the original setup).

In case someone else has this issue and needs to fully delete a certificate generated by Certbot here are the commands that I used:

```
sudo certbot delete
cd /etc/apache2/sites-enabled
ls
sudo nano 000-default.conf
    # Remove the redirect
sudo rm 000-default-le-ssl.conf
    # Also any file other SSL files such as [000-default-le-ssl.conf.sav]
sudo certbot --apache
    # enter both Domains "example.com www.example.com"
sudo service apache2 restart
```